# Python GTK 3+: Is there a "enter" like signal I can use for Combobox?

Tags: python, gtk3

So I know for the Button widget you can use the enter and leave signals to get it to perform actions upon hover over. I want to do the same for the Combobox (I have a dropdown menu I want to be able to access upon hovering over it). However, the enter signal doesn't seem to exist for this. Is there an alternative I could use? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, the `enter` signal in the `Gtk.Button` class is deprecated.

You should use the `enter-notify-event` signal, which belongs to the `Gtk.Widget` class and it is inherited by all its childs, `Gtk.ComboBox` included.